# Error MIME en proyecto nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodejs, express

Estoy haciendo una pagina web, con nodeJS, expressJS, bootstrap 4.0. Dentro del proyecto uso partials con EJS. En este momento tengo un problema, cuando establezco una ruta para cuando por URL me pasen una que yo no tenga declarada, me genera el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que contiene mi archivo de rutas:

```
    router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("landing.ejs", { title: "Bienvenido" });
});

//Ruta /principal - principal.ejs
router.get("/principal", (req, res) => {
  res.render("principal.ejs", { title: "Bienvenido" });
});

//Ruta /nosotros - nosotros.ejs
router.get("/nosotros", (req, res) => {
  res.render("nosotros.ejs", { title: "Nosotros" });
});

//Ruta /contactanos - contactanos.ejs
router.get("/contactanos", (req, res) => {
  res.render("contactanos.ejs", { title: "Contactanos" });
});
```

Es cuando creo esta ruta que me genera el error que muestro en la imagen:

```
router.get("/*", (req, res) => {
        res.send("Prueba");
    });
```

Adjunto también una imagen con la estructura del proyecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adicional también, lo que yo he podido notar, es que al parecer los archivos CSS locales es como si se sobrescribieran o no llamara a los archivos del directorio public, que es donde tengo todos los archivos estaticos (CSS locales, imagenes, etc).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realmente no se como solucionarlo, si alguien me puede ayudar, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quien pueda interesarle y le ocurra este mismo error, encontré una forma de solucionarlo, no se si sea la mejor, pero me funciono.

Lo que hice fue usar un midleware, el cual valida si el status es 404. En caso de ser así, redireccione a mi vista html para el manejo de estos casos (una pagina tipo, recurso no encontrado).

Adjunto imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe de alguna mejor solucion, por que lo que hice es mala practica o algo, estoy atento.

Saludos!